# How can I append data from multiple CSVs to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd  
from csv import DictReader  
import glob  

with open(path) as f: 
DictReader_obj = csv.DictReader(f)  
for item in DictReader_obj:  
      reader = dict(item)  
      print(reader)
```

That code works fine for a single csv, now I am trying to loop through various related csv's

to initialize  `list_df = []` and tried it with `list_df= {}` and even `df = [{ }]`

```
for csvfile in csvfiles:  
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:  
        DictReader_obj = DictReader(f, fieldnames = ['Symbols', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', `'Close', 'Volumn']

    for item in DictReader_obj:
           reader = dict(item)
           list_df.append(reader)
```

is only giving the contents of one csv file. My type(reader) is dict and my type(list_df) is list.

What am I missing? Any suggestions as I tried my due diligence researching and reading and consider myself learning this art.

Was expecting my contents of all my CSVs in a dictionary. I understand I can use yFinance to grab info, but I have CSVs and prefer to have them local to avoid any yFinance threshold bans

example the output expected:

```
A                   Date    Open    High    Close    Volumn
             xx/xx/xxxx    xxx.xx   xxx.xx  xxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx
             xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
AA           xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx 
             xx/xx/xxxx    xxx.xx   xxx.xx  xxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
             xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
AAPL         xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
             xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
             xx/xx/xxxx   xxxx.xx  xxxx.xx xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxx  
....
```

Comment: Please properly comment your code with three backtics (`) so that we can read it

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas.concat to aggregate all your csv in a single dataframe. In the following path_files is a list of path to your csv files. This has the advantages to keep your data sources in the index if needed.

```
import pandas as pd
reader = (
    (pd.read_csv(path_file_i) from path_file_i in path_files), 
    axis=0,
    keys=path_files
    )
```

If you want to keep it as a dictionary, you need to initiate reader as a dict and then assign your csv to an item in your dictionary.

```
reader = {}
for item in DictReader_obj: ` 
   reader[item] = ...
```